# Метод whereValid в Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Изучаю Laravel. Наткнулся на метод whereValid, который используется в этом коде:

```
/**
 * Get comments paginate.
 *
 * @param  int  $nbrPages
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
public function getAll($nbrPages, $parameters)
{
    return Comment::with ([
            'ingoing',
            'user',
            'post' => function ($query) { $query->withCount('comments'); }
        ])
        ->latest()
        ->when ($parameters['new'], function ($query) {
            $query->has ('ingoing');
        })->when ($parameters['valid'], function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->whereValid(true);
            });
        })->paginate($nbrPages);
}
```

Не понимаю, какую задачу он выполняет? Не могу нигде найти хотя бы слово о нём. Буду благодарен за любое разъяснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это "фишка" Laravel такая. В название метода включать имя переменной с большой буквы. Т.е:

```
$query->whereValid(true);
```

означает

```
$query->where('valid', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не секрет, какой репозиторий рассматриваете?
А так, судя по всему в модели User (если точнее, то у Модели Comment есть связанная модель, отношением user(), отсюда можно предположить и название модели) есть метод

```
function scopeWhereValid(){
   ...
}
```

Именно он вызывается в данном случае.